# Who was attending the synagogues in Jesus times?

Tags: acts, synagogue, cultural-analysis

Were there only Jewish men, or women as well?

Were there children? If so, of what age?

> 42 As Paul and Barnabas were going out, the people repeatedly begged
> to have these things spoken to them the next Sabbath. 43 Now when the
> meeting of the synagogue had broken up, many of the Jews and the
> God-fearing proselytes followed Paul and Barnabas, who were speaking
> to them and urging them to continue in the grace of God. (Acts
> 13:42-43, NASB® 2020)
>
> 1 In Iconium they entered the synagogue of the Jews together, and
> spoke in such a way that a large number of people believed, both of
> Jews and of Greeks. 2 But the unbelieving Jews stirred up the minds of
> the Gentiles and embittered them against the brothers. (Acts 14:1-2,
> NASB® 2020)
>
> 1 Now when they had traveled through Amphipolis and Apollonia, they
> came to Thessalonica, where there was a synagogue of the Jews. 2 And
> according to Paul's custom, he visited them, and for three Sabbaths
> reasoned with them from the Scriptures, 3 explaining and giving
> evidence that the Christ had to suffer and rise from the dead, and
> saying, "This Jesus whom I am proclaiming to you is the Christ." 4 And
> some of them were persuaded and joined Paul and Silas, along with a
> large number of the God-fearing Greeks and a significant number of the
> leading women. (Acts 17:1-4, NASB® 2020)

Thank you.

Comment: Jesus asked questions in the temple at the age of twelve, so one assumes children were involved, but the temple is not the synagogue, exactly. Deuteronomy 31:12 'men women and children' but that is not, exactly the synagogue again, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

There was a woman in the synagogue in Luke 13:

> 10 On a Sabbath Jesus was teaching in one of the synagogues, 11and a **woman** was there who had been crippled by a spirit for eighteen years. She was bent over and could not straighten up at all.

There is a riddle in the Jerusalem Talmud, Berachot 9d:

> In a town in which all the residents are priests, when they spread their hands [in the synagogue] and give the priestly blessing, who responds ‘Amen’?

The answer is

> the women and children.

This implies that women and children did attend synagogue services as assumed by the Jerusalem Talmud.

Comment: Truly excellent and concise answer!! +1.